# How to prevent an only absolute positioned element from sending a link?

Tags: html, css

[image]I just want the icon to prevent the link from sending it! As you see on the pic, the heart icon is wrapped with the img, h2 and p by an anchor tag.  By the way, i tried the property pointer-events:none; but it didn't work.
This is the code:

```
<a href="#">
   <div class="wrapper">
   <img src="#"/>
   <div class="details">
     <h2>...</h2>
     <p>...</p>
     <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
  </div>
  </div>
</a>




.fa-heart {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    transition: color 600ms linear;
 }
```

Comment: Could you just put the icon outside the a element?

Comment: Use this `<a href="#"> Your Icon </a>` this is what you wanted.

Comment: Non actually i just want to disable the heart icon form sending the whole link while the other parts of the link want to work properly !